# Have installed python3-BeautifulSoup-1:3.2.0-4.fc16 in Fedora 16 but can't use it

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, fedora

I've installed BeautifulSoup for Python 3 (python3-BeautifulSoup-1:3.2.0-4.fc16) on Fedora 16(64bit) using the Add/Remove Software GUI tool. It appears to have installed correctly (yum info python3-BeautifulSoup shows 'Repo: Installed') but when I try to import BeautifulSoup (using import BeautifulSoup statement) in the interactive shell I get an 'ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup' message.

I've also got BeautifulSoup for Python 2 (python-BeautifulSoup-1:3.2.0-4.fc16) installed h working fine with Python 2.7.2.

The summary appears weird (Monitor filesystem events with Python under Linux) though the descrition makes sense. Where do I start?

I'm new to Python (trying to learn Python3 in my spare time) and I'm not a programmer. I'm trying to learn by writing simple code and following [code examples](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576551-simple-web-crawler/) (hence the need for BeautifulSoup.) Please assume minimal Python (and linux) knowledge.

Comment: I think the `BeautifulSoup` *module* (not class) was renamed to `bs4`. You might try: `import bs4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ repoquery -l python3-BeautifulSoup
/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.0.0b3-py3.2.egg-info
/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages/bs4
/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just begun working my way through repoquery (trying to understand its output). I'm assuming the highlighted text is highlighted for a reason.

Comment: Yes. It shows stuff in `sys.path`, and the beginning of a package.

Comment: I'm having to go to first principles (for both linux and Python). I think I know what a package is (and an egg - a python package for releasing python software) but if bernie hadn't mentioned bs4 I wouldn't have worked out that it was the module name. Anyway I'm off to bed now.